# How to zoom out of the backdrop in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

The *Backdrop Image* in my compositor is too zoomed in because my image is high res. How can I zoom out?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The four controls for manipulating a *Background Image* in the *Compositor*:

1. <kbd>V</kbd> zooms out.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> zooms in.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> pans around.
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> fits backdrop to the available area.

Also note the changes to the *Node Editor Properties panel*, such as the addition of the *Backdrop dropdown*, which, among other things like the hotkeys, allows for precision zooming.

[image]

Refer to the [Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/introduction.html#backdrop) for additional info.

Comment: you are doing the lord's work

Comment: @JosephFarah Glad to help!

Comment: @ShadyPuck the wiki reference you are using is very old, you should start referring to the [current manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/contents.html)

Comment: @sambler Perhaps, but it is still relevant.

Comment: Yes, the wiki as been deprecated as a Blender manual for some time, besides that is still the manual for the (very) old Blender 2.4 series which is desperately outdated, if you reference the wiki it's better to reference at least for the latest available version.

Comment: In the 2.83 beta, both v and alt v zoom out. Has that changed since 2016?

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 It’s possible, though I’m not seeing anything about it online, so I’d guess it’s just a bug (it is a beta, after all). Does the properties panel Zoom slider still work?

Answer (score 4):

Hover the mouse over the backdrop and hit <kbd>V</kbd> until the backdrop is zoomed to desire.